# facebook mobile app request dialog with flex issue

Tags: ios, facebook, apache-flex

I am making a webviewstage in flex mobile to display the dialog app request url of facebook , but when I am writing in the text input to autocomplete my friends, it never load anyone... what is happening...? theres another way to invite friends to my app in flex mobile?... I' am working with IOS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have been in the similar problem 2 weeks ago, but I managed to create a native extension , which is an iOS library you embed into your flex project, it displays the FB dialog with app request with the list of your suggested friends, you can do the same, if you need more help, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, do you have the library link page?